# How to use main method to randomly generate a day in a month ? Any ideas?

Tags: java

I just started some Java and got some tasks from my friend, but i don't know what to do. I have to use my method `getDayInMonth` to find a specific day in a month and repeat it 100 times in my `main method` which is `BirthdaySimulation`. So for example, for June, the day is the sixth, how should i do this?

Comment: A 'day' ? 6 is not the day of June, can you be more precise ?

Comment: Consult your friend for vague help.  StackExchange is for clear, well explained problems, where effort has been shown by the poster before asking the StackExchange community for help.

Comment: I am pretty sure he just meant sixth of June for example. So if i wanted to find sixth of June from the month June.

Comment: Provide several examples of input, and the expected output in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the program will generate a random number in range (1 to 30). Is this what you want?

```
 import java.util.Random;
 class Test{
     public static void main(String []args){
            Random rnd=new Random();

            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                int day=rnd.nextInt(30)+1;
                System.out.println("Random Day ("+(i+1)+"):" + day);
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will use it to aid me.

Comment: You are welcome. if it is a correct answer, please mark my answer as a correct one. if you need further help, just let me know.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make sure the number generator repeats itself 100 times?

Comment: yes,, look at the code,, I just updated it..